# How to response with MIME code on oat++ endpoint

Tags: oat++

How do I set the MIME code on a endpoint response?

I see no documentation about that available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to add a `Content-Type` header to the response:

```
auto response = createResponse(Status::CODE_200, "OK");
response->putHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
return response;
```